# Cant install package in atom

Tags: atom-editor

I am having trouble installing any form of package in atom. I used a fresh install of Atom and Python 3.7.3 in Windows 10 64-bit.
I tried installing Platformio-ide-terminal but it resulted in an error
Then also tried installing atom-ide-terminal resulting in a similar error.

When going through the error I noticed one common line in both the errors:

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Users\Ashwin Belbase\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.EXE", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
```

(edit)
tried both through the atom>preferences>install and the CLI using apm install  same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update, August 20, 2019**

The issue was fixed in [Atom v1.40.1](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/tag/v1.40.1)

**Old answer**

The said package is currently not working with Atom v1.39, since it includes a major update for the underlying Electron framework.

You can try and rebuild some of the package's native modules. To do so, run `apm rebuild` inside the `~/.atom/packages/platformio-ide-terminal` folder.

If that doesn't work, a workaround is to downgrade Atom to v1.38.x and wait for a fix. You can follow this [discussion](https://discuss.atom.io/t/cannot-install-platformio-ide-terminal-2-9-1-on-atom/67012/13) or subscribe to the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/19705) for updates.